# Chain command in makefile to connect to postgres container via the IP

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker, makefile

I have created a postgres container which is running detached.

I would like to be able to create a command in a Makefile `make psql` where I can connect from my host machine to the container via psql and check data is being inserted correctly.

I am struggling with how to compose the makefile command. So far I got:

Makefile

```
PG_CONTAINER=project_ch_pg_run_1

test_ip_1:
        docker exec -it project_ch_pg_run_1 hostname -i


test_ip_2:
        docker exec -it $(PG_CONTAINER) hostname -i

test_ip_3:
        IP=$$(docker exec -it $(PG_CONTAINER) hostname -i); \
        echo "Here's the IP of the container:$(IP)"

pslq:
        IP=$$(docker exec -it project_ch_pg_run_1 hostname -i); \
        psql postgres://ch_user:ch_pass@$(IP):5432/ch_dib
```

Results:

#### 1 works fine.

`make test_ip_1`

```
docker exec -it project_ch_pg_run_1 hostname -i
192.168.96.2
```

#### 2 variable substitution works.

```
docker exec -it project_ch_pg_run_1 hostname -i
192.168.96.2
```

#### 3 storing result of command in `IP` variable and performing substitution does not work.

```
IP=$(docker exec -it project_ch_pg_run_1 hostname -i); \
echo "Here's the IP of the container:"
Here's the IP of the container:
```

#### 4 storing result of command in `IP` variable and use it to compose pg URI does not work.

```
IP=$(docker exec -it project_ch_pg_run_1 hostname -i); \
psql postgres://ch_user:ch_pass@:5432/ch_dib
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'psql' failed
make: *** [psql] Error 2
```

I have been going around for hours but I cannot seem to find the right syntax to chain these commands - any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep clear in your mind the difference between *make* variables and *shell* variables.

Here:

```
test_ip_3:
        IP=$$(docker exec -it $(PG_CONTAINER) hostname -i); \
        echo "Here's the IP of the container:$(IP)"
```

You correctly escape the invocation of the `docker` program using `$$(...)` so that this syntax is not considered a make variable.

But then you set the *shell* variable `IP`, and in the next line you use `$(IP)` which is a reference to the *make* variable `IP`, which you've never set.

You need to use:

```
test_ip_3:
        IP=$$(docker exec -it $(PG_CONTAINER) hostname -i); \
        echo "Here's the IP of the container:$$IP"
```

to print the value of the *shell* variable `IP`.